# Force required to propel mass in vacuum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, estimation, space

I'm not mathematically inclined. At. All. I'm a massage therapist and mental health provider. I am, however, writing a book that takes place in space.

My main character (MC) is 4'11" and weighs 95#/~43kg. She's in a modified EVA suit that increases her weight by 20#/~9kg. She's currently using a piece of hull debris as a chair while she waits for her rescue.

Assume deep space outside of an nearby planets' gravitational pull. (Her intergalactic ark is traveling from Proxima Centauri B to the TRAPPIST system.)

She needs to "jump" from her debris-chair to a ship that is within 25m. She has a can of pressurized propellant that will give her one "big" boost to close the distance between chair and ship.

QUESTION: How big does the debris-chair need to be in order for this ridiculous scenario to be "plausible?"

I hope I've explained this well enough to garner some answers. 
Thanks!

Comment: Its a little confusing, are you asking how big the can has to be? Or how heavy the chair has to be for her to be able to jump against ? Regardless, the answer would be not very much, a pound of propellant or a 10 pound chair might be enough, assuming she didnt have a very large velocity away from the ship to begin with...

Comment: I think it's already plausible.. I mean she can coast, right? Check out: https://www.wired.com/story/sorry-sandra-bullock-a-fire-extinguisher-is-a-lousy-thruster/ ...Looking forward to seeing "From Massage Therapist to Hugo Winner" in the news.

Comment: You need to say what time period you are talking about for the transfer to take place,  is the rescue ship moving relative to the chair?  how much air has she left? You know, ........ dramatic touches :). Best of luck with the book.  Arthur C. Clarke, "Take a Deep Breath" (1957) has a slightly similar idea.

Comment: *I'm not mathematically inclined...* I doubt this. I believe everyone is capable of grasping mathematics. I think you mean to say you aren't good and doing specific calculations that weren't taught well to you.

Comment: The (easy) math and physics is explained here: https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/momentum/Lesson-1/Momentum

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [worldbuilding.se]

Comment: @Kostas, I'm asking how big the chair would need to be for her to reach the passing ship. I need her to "jump" from the chair and barely miss the ship. The propellant, which is needed for later in the story, would provide a boost once she lost momentum to reach a moving ship. Did that help or make it worse?

Comment: @JEB hahaha. I'll let you know when that happens. Thanks for the article!

Comment: @StudyStudy the rescue ship is moving perpendicularly to her stable position at a rate of .15km/h. At this point, she has 50% oxygen left in a 12 hour tank (the story takes place in 2201).

Comment: @AaronStevens well, thank you for that encouragement. My calculator skills are pretty awesome.

Comment: @StudyStudy re your second comment about the (easy) math. I go blind and dumb when I have to read about math. Or how it's supposed to work. I'd show you my stats class scores, but don't think this is an appropriate forum. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: In case it's not totally clear, this is doable just by kicking the "chair" in the opposite direction. The can of propellant isn't necessary, but it's handy if she needs to adjust her trajectory. BTW, her suit (& air tank) must be pretty amazing to be that light. Also, that ark is interstellar, not intergalactic.

Comment: Don't give up.......https://youtu.be/PXwStduNw14

Comment: @PM2Ring thank you for the simple and clear answer. Also, I appreciate you clarifying the type of Ark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be precise, if she kicks a chair weighting 10 pounds at a speed of 3ft/sec away from the direction she wishes to go, she will gain a speed of
3ft/sec * 10#/115#  equal approx. 0.3 ft/sec. She will get to the ship in 25m * 3ft/m / 0.3ft/sec = 250 seconds

All this complicated by the fact that she has to aim really well, not in the direction  where the ship is now but where it will be in 250 seconds = 4min. I did not take into account the distance the ship will go in this time, but that is just about 10 meters, so will not change the calculation too much.

Answer (score 2):

In deep space objects in motion tend to stay in motion.  The bigger the chair the bigger a kick she will get from pushing it away.  But as long as that ship stays within 25m of her initial position, she is going to get there.

Ideally, you will take away her can of propellant, make the chair very light, and let her move at like 1 cm per second for 2500 seconds in order to get there.

In fact, forget the chair and the propellant, just have her throw a tiny spec of debris from her suit.  She should throw it in the opposite direction as she wishes to travel.